# Where is the Wiper Relay/Control Module located on a 1994-1998 Ford Mustang???

Tags: electrical, ford, mustang, windshield-wipers

I am trying to repair my wipers, there is no voltage in the wires that connects to the wiper motor.  I checked the fuses and current is passing through them, so they are ok.  I think the Wiper Relay (or wiper control module) went bad, but I do not know where it is located.  Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you ever find the where the module was located? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a six wire connector plugged into your wiper motor.

1. Yellow/Red to wiper control module wiper motor ground
2. Black/Pink to wiper control module wiper motor switch
3. Dark Green +12 volt in Accessory and Run
4. Black Chassis Ground
5. Dark Blue/Orange to wiper control module wiper motor low
6. White to wiper control module hi input

If there is no voltage on the Dark Green wire with the ignition switch on then Fuse 2 (30 amp) in the instrument panel fuse box is blown or you have an open connection between the Windshield wiper motor and the fuse panel.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering! I already checked the fuse.  I even replaced it with one of the same measurement, and its still not working.  Do you know what lies between the fuse box and the wiper motor??  The Washer does not work either btw.

Comment: @bombillazo Next step is to check for power at the fuse with the ignition on. If you have power at the fuse check for power at pin 4 and 13 Dark Green wire on the Wiper control Module. This circuit also supplies the washer motor with power.

Comment: Ok, I checked the current passing through the fuse, its ok, I checked the Voltage at the cable connecting to the wire, and its about .02 Volts, thats way to low, so something between them is not right.  I have to know where the wiper relay/control module lies in order to fix it:)

Answer (score 1):

It's behind the glove compartment to the right there is a black box 2screws take the screws off the black box. Pull it out and there's another small black box its the wiper control mod. That's your problem